# getting error while installing build in conanfiles

Tags: cmake, conan

I've got some problem with conan package manager When I run this command on my command line

```
conan install .. --build=missing
```

but i got some error in my **conanfile.py**

> Hello/0.1@mohammad/stable: ERROR: Package '90ee443cae5dd5c1b4861766ac14dc6fae231a92' build failed
>
> Hello/0.1@mohammad/stable: WARN: Build folder /home/mohammad/.conan/data/Hello/0.1/mohammad/stable/build/90ee443cae5dd5c1b4861766ac14dc6fae231a92
>
> ERROR: Hello/0.1@mohammad/stable: Error in build() method, line 14 cmake = CMake(self.settings)
>   ConanException: First argument of CMake() has to be ConanFile. Use CMake(self)

This is my **conanfile.py**

```
 import os, platform

 class HelloConan(ConanFile):
 name = "Hello"
 version = "0.1"
 settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

 def source(self):
    self.run("git clone https://github.com/memsharded/hello.git")

 def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self.settings)
    self.run('cmake hello %s' % (cmake.command_line))
    self.run('cmake --build . %s' % cmake.build_config)

 def package(self):
    self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="hello")
    self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
    self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

 def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["hello"]
```

Comment: It seems that you are using a deprecated syntax. Not only for the ``CMake(self.settings)``, but you might also take advantage of the ``cmake.configure()``, ``cmake.build()``, etc., methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message clearly says what's wrong:

> First argument of CMake() has to be ConanFile. Use CMake(self)

You are passing `self.settings` instead:

```
cmake = CMake(self.settings)
```

Comment: To extend on the answer, which is correct, it seems that you are using a very outdated recipe style, much before conan 1.0 (i.e. while conan was still in beta). I'd recommend making sure that you are using the latest documentation. If you found such ``CMake(self.settings)`` in the docs, please report it inmediately to http://github.com/conan-io/docs, so it gets fixed.